# ¿How can i get the exact date and hour of an event?

Tags: ros, rostime

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello guys,
I'm having a problem with ROS Time, I need for a protect the exact Time and the exact Hour at which some event happened.
I tried with ros time, but I don't see any equivalences between the double number 1486371808.656735126 and the Date and Hour Mon Feb 6 04:03:32 COT 2017.

Does anyone have suggestions?

Thank you very much

```
[ INFO] [1486371808.656553045]: Slot ID Bloque A - Casilla 2 with CHANGE
[ INFO] [1486371808.656735126]: The sensor in the slot Bloque A - Casilla 2 was ACTIVATED
rosrun sound_play say.py 'La herramienta fue dejada'1.48637e+12
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# date
lun feb  6 04:03:32 COT 2017
root@raspberrypi:/home/pi#
```

---

```
if(m_Slots.at(c).getState() == true){
    ROS_INFO("The sensor in the slot %s was ACTIVATED", m_Slots.at(c).getID().c_str());
    double timeDouble = ros::WallTime::now().toSec()*1000.;
    std::ostringstream sstream;
    sstream << timeDouble;
    std::string timeString = sstream.str();
    string message = "rosrun sound_play say.py 'La herramienta fue dejada'"+timeString;
    std::cout << message << std::endl;
    //system("rosrun sound_play say.py 'La herramienta fue dejada'");
    //TODO definir hora de recepcion del usuario en la herramienta con getTimePointActivated
}else{
    ROS_INFO("The sensor in the slot %s is DEACTIVATED", m_Slots.at(c).getID().c_str());
    //system("rosrun sound_play say.py 'The tool has been taken'");
    //TODO definir hora de entrega al usuario en la herramienta con getTimePointActivated
}
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/254261/%C2%BFhow-can-i-get-the-exact-date-and-hour-of-an-event?/) by [fhfonsecaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/28517/fhfonsecaa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 90 on 2017-02-09

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The time is in [Unix time](http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm), seconds since 1970.  You can transform it to a more readable format with the functions in `<ctime>` for C++ or the `time` module in Python.

---

Originally posted by [Bill Smart](https://answers.ros.org/users/96/bill-smart/) with karma: 1263 on 2017-02-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [fhfonsecaa](https://answers.ros.org/users/28517/fhfonsecaa/) on 2017-02-09**:
Thank you very much,  worked perfectly.